# Any solution for "no dial tone" when connecting modem to internet

Tags: 11.10, modem

Problem when connecting modem (zte ac682) to internet

```
--> WvDial: Internet dialer version 1.61
--> Cannot get information for serial port.
--> Initializing modem.
--> Sending: ATZ
ATZ
OK
--> Sending: ATQ0 V1 E1 S0=0 &C1 &D2 +FCLASS=0
ATQ0 V1 E1 S0=0 &C1 &D2 +FCLASS=0
OK
--> Modem initialized.
--> Sending: ATDT#777
--> Waiting for carrier.
ATDT#777
NO DIALTONE
--> No dial tone.
--> Disconnecting at Sun Oct 30 11:54:26 2011
```

Answer (score 1):

No dial tone means that the telephone line is disconnected. It could be:

a) the modem is not plugged into the telephone line.

b) the telephone line between the modem and the telephone exchange is broken somewhere.

c) the telephone account has been disconnected by the telephone company.

Or

d) you have set Wvdial to use touch tone dialing instead of pulse tone dialing. Which method does your telephone system use?

The command ATDT#777 is instructing the modem to dial (D = dial). The modem tries to do this twice. It fails. The letter T = touch tone dialing. A letter P would equal pulse tone dialing. See this link and study the Hayes Command set.

[The command set used by dial-up modems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization_string#Modem_initialization)